# Do C compilers optimize the execution stack in case of successive function calls?

Tags: c, embedded, compiler-optimization, callstack

I have a basic question about call stack behavior. 
I would like to know how the system manage the call stack memory when a function is called at the end of an other function.

For example:

```
void FunctionOne(void)
{
    [...] // Various code operations
    FunctionTwo();
}


void FunctionTwo(void)
{
    [...] // Various code operation
    FunctionThree();
}


void FunctionThree(void)
{
    [...] // Various code operation
    FunctionFour();
    [...] // Various code operation
}
```

Does the call stack memory is cleaned when the execution jumps from FunctionOne() to FunctionTwo() because there is no instruction after the call of FunctionTwo()?

Is the stack memory keeping the entire level of execution when it goes from FunctionTwo() to FunctionThree()?

Or maybe I'm wrong since the beginning about how the call stack works and its purpose?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, the call stack is not "cleaned" when you call a function, otherwise it wouldn't be a stack. I suggest you read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)?

Comment: It is however likely that the compiler "inlines" one or several function calls, in which case there won't be any stacking of return address etc at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed the calls to `functionTwo()` from `functionOne()` and to `functionThree()` from `functionTwo()` could be generated as jumps after some specific adjustments to account for the arguments and local variables of the caller (what you can *stack cleanup*). This is called *tail call optimization*.  They could also be generated inline, the code of the called function becoming part of the calling function.

Whether the C compiler performs tail call optimisation, inline generation or some more advanced trick is a quality of implementation issue. Doing so may improve code speed, and reduce stack usage, but make debugging more difficult as the call stack may be confusing to trace.

The Standard imposes no requirements regarding this, the compiler must generate code *as if* the calls take place normally.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !

Comment: Some compilers support `#pragma noreturn` on functions and will then be able to format the stack frame accordingly.

Comment: @tofro: I believe `#pragma noreturn` tells the compiler that a function never returns, either because it terminates the program or because it is designed to have an endless loop. No connection to the current question.

Comment: Sure is. *noreturn* functions can have an optimized (smaller) stack frame because they can trash the stack.

Comment: @tofro: OK, but the is no indication that any of the functions in the OP's question have this property.

Answer (score -2):

Should be like this photo:
[memory stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwU18.jpg)

Comment: While this answer is correct, one with the same information but in written form is more accessible thus will be better for more users.  Also some explanation of why the stack works that way would be helpful.